# jQuery code from previous page (Homepage) affecting new page (Posts page) navigated to and causing error

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, ecmascript-6

In my react code, I included some jQuery code to make the home page components fade into visibility on scroll. It works fine, but when I navigate to another page like the 'all posts' page and then try to scroll, it gives an error saying

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'top')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'top')
```

this 'top' comes from the method checking the position of the element, if it has scrolled into view, the jQuery in former homepage is running and affecting the new page causing error.

I tried putting conditional statement to check before code execution and a try catch line of code but it isn't catching this particular error neither is the conditional. How can I fix this? Is there a better way to write the jQuery code to avoid this error? The jQuery Code can be found below.

NB: This error usually goes away anytime I refresh the new page, but it is a bug I feel would affect user experience and needs to be fixed. One idea that came to my head is to restrict the JavaScript action to only the page where it was written, or disable java script of an old page when you've navigated to the new page in order to prevent the persisting JavaScript from previous pages, what would be a way to do it in this instance?

```
$(()=>{//jquery to make the homepage components become visible on scroll
            try{
            $(document).on("scroll", function() {
                var pageTop = $(document).scrollTop();//get numerical value of top of page
                var pageBottom = pageTop + $(window).height();//get numerical value of bottom of page
                var tags = $(".icon-box");//select icon boxes
                
                //this code makes the 'what we offer' icon boxes become visible on scroll
                if ($(tags[0]).position().top){
                    for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
                    var tag = tags[i];
                    
                    if ($(tag)?.position().top < pageBottom) {
                        $(tag).addClass("visible");
                    } else {
                        $(tag).removeClass("visible");
                    }
                }}else{console.log('Not on Page')}
            });}catch(err){console.log(err)}
        });
```

Comment: I suggest refactoring your code to remove the  jQuery code, if you are truly using React as your tags indicate. Mixing the two is generally a code smell that something has gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var tags = $(".icon-box");//select icon boxes

console.log("Number of icon boxes : " + $(tags).length);

if($(tags).length) {
 console.log('Icon boxes are available on the page.');
} else {
 console.log('No Icon boxes are available on the page.');
}
```

```css
.icon-box {
 padding: 1rem;
 background: #CCC;
 margin: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="icon-box">Icon 1</div>
<div class="icon-box">Icon 2</div>
<div class="icon-box">Icon 3</div>
```

You can check the length (length is a number of elements with particular selector) of elements which is available on the page.

**Example code:**

```js
if ( $( "#myDiv" ).length ) {
    $( "#myDiv" ).show();
}
```

**OR**

```js
if ( $( "#myDiv" ).length > 0 ) {
    $( "#myDiv" ).show();
}
```

You need to put part of your code in one more IF condition as shown below.

```js
if ($(tags).length) {
    //this code makes the 'what we offer' icon boxes become visible on scroll
    if ($(tags[0]).position().top) {
        for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
            var tag = tags[i];

            if ($(tag)?.position().top < pageBottom) {
                $(tag).addClass("visible");
            } else {
                $(tag).removeClass("visible");
            }
        }
    }
} else { console.log('Not on Page') }
```

I hope this will be helpful.

Thanks, Jignesh Raval

Comment: Thanks for your input, its still behaving the same way even with the extra If condition. I was wondering if there is a way to restrict the JavaScript action to only the page where it was written, or disable java script of an old page when you've navigated to the new page. In my code generally some JavaScript behaviors still persists to another page even after leaving it two pages behind until you refresh. Do you maybe know how to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the code a bit but also check if there ARE any such elements before trying to access the first ones position.

EDIT: I had `forEach(` which was a syntax error on my part - I could have used this native JavaScript function but we have the jQuery object already so we can use `.each()` reference: https://api.jquery.com/each/

`tags` returns jQuery for the selector `$(".icon-box");` in this case.  `each(` then calls the function `(function() {` for each (if any) of those elements with `this` being that ONE element.

I also altered to use an arguably slightly more descriptive `$(tags).first()` ref: https://api.jquery.com/first/

IF for some reason you need the index you can use this form: `.each(function( index )`

I added a nasty element just to induce scroll.

```js
var didOne = false;
$(() => {
  try {
    $(document).on("scroll", function() {
      const pageTop = $(document).scrollTop();
      const pageBottom = pageTop + $(window).height();
      const tags = $(".icon-box");
      const hasTags = !!$(tags).length;
      const $window = $(window);
      if (hasTags) {

        const distance = tags.first().offset().top;
        tags.each(function() {
          const tag = this;
          const distance = $(this).offset().top;
          const wScrollT = $window.scrollTop();
          let isONTop = wScrollT >= distance;
          $(tags).first().text("Dist:" + distance +":"+wScrollT+":" +isONTop);
          $(tag).toggleClass("visible", isONTop);
        });
      }
      if (!$(tags).length && !didOne) {
        didOne = true; // avoid excess logging
        console.log('No tags on Page');
      }
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
});
$('.add-one').one('click', function(event) {
  $('.bigger-me').prepend('<div class="icon-box">icon box</div>');
})
```

```css
.bigger-me {
  border: solid 1px #00ff00;
  padding-top: 300px;
  padding-bottom: 300px;
  background-color: #00ff0020;
}
.visible{border: solid green 3px;}
.icon-box {
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="add-one" type="button">Add one just to test</button>
<div class="bigger-me">Here we are today is the best day of the day!</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, the forEach method is causing a run time error, I'd appreciate if you can explain its function a bit more

Comment: That was my bad - a typo.  I updated with the proper form and some notes:

Comment: I also added a button just to add an icon to show it works without and with once the "tag" element is added